# Ошибка логики не могу найти

Tags: javascript, логика

Хочу создать примитивную логику при помощи массивов, чтобы при вводе номера месяца выдавало слово. Но где-то ошибся, а где понять не могу, дебаггер пошагово не идет по скрипту.

```
document.getElementById('calc').onclick = function () {
let p = document.getElementById('language');
p = parseInt(p);

let lang = ['ru', 'en'];
let monthru = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Декабрь'];
let monthen = ['January', 'February', 'Marth', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November', 'December'];

let b = monthru.map (function (y) {
for (let y = (p-1); p < monthru.length;){
}
});
console.log(b[y]);

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "text" id="language">
    <button id="calc">Распознать</button>
    <select>
    <option>ru</option>
    <option>en</option>
    </select>
<script type="text/javascript"src="1.js">  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вбей в консоль результат этой операции - let p = document.getElementById('language'); 
и посмотри что ты в результате пытаешься parseInt-ить и от чего отнимаешь единицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('calc').onclick = function() {

  let months = {
    ru: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
    en: ['January', 'February', 'Marth', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
  };
  
  let lang = document.getElementById('language').value;
  let monthIndex = +document.getElementById('month').value - 1; 
  let monthName = months[lang][monthIndex];

  console.log(lang, monthIndex, monthName);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="month" value="1">
<button id="calc">Распознать</button>
<select id="language">
  <option>ru</option>
  <option>en</option>
</select>
```